# How to use OR and AND with where clause in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

-- Query I want to use :

```
select * from users where (email like '%email@email.com%' OR username like 'myusername') AND (password like '%1234@abcde%')
```

-- My laravel code for above query is :

```
$getInfo = Users::where('password','like','%'.$request->password.'%')
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->where('email','like','%'.$request->username.'%')
                ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$req->username.'%');
            })->get();
```

Here I am getting an error **Undefined variable: request**

Comment: You can use WhereRaw( ((email like '%'.$email.'%' OR username like '.$username.') AND (password like '%'.$password.'%')) ). Also its not my place to ask but why aren't you encrypting password while saving?

Comment: I am using laravel so I guess it would be good if I should use laravel functions rather than using raw query.

Comment: Its inbuild laravel function. At the end all the eloquent queries are changed by laravel to SQL commands for sql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$request`  to your closure function like `use ($request)`

```
$getInfo = Users::where('password','like','%'.$request->password.'%')
            ->where(function($query) use ($request){
                $query->where('email','like','%'.$request->username.'%')
                ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$req->username.'%');
            })->get();
```

Also its not a good idea to search user details using like with wildcard (%) on both sides, it should be just `like` without wildcards or just use equality comparison `=`

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works but it does not return any data.

Comment: It returns only [] with message "no properties" in my ajax response

Comment: Can you check you have exact data in DB against the data you receive from `$request`   also do check the final sql generated by query builder using `toSql()` instead of `get()`

Comment: it returns select * from `users` where `password` = ? and (`email` = ? or `username` = ?)

Comment: @Moksh check binding values for these (?) placeholders  and then evaluate your query

Comment: Thank you. I have checked it and it was issue due to Hash::make param. At the time of account creation I have inserted password with Hash::make and when I am retrieving it I am converting string to Hash::make. Both the time I am getting different strings

Answer (score 1):

```
$getInfo = Users::where('password','like','%'.$request->password.'%')
            ->where(function($query) use ($request){
                $query->where('email','like','%'.$request->username.'%')
                ->orWhere('username','like','%'.$request->username.'%');
            })->get();
```

You have can variables to closure using `use ($request)`.

You have also a typo

change

```
->orWhere('username','like','%'.$req->username.'%');
```

to

```
->orWhere('username','like','%'.$request->username.'%');
```

Comment: Thank you for your support and yes it was my typo.